PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS_MISSING_FOR_PUBSUB_TOPIC Error Despite Correct Pub/Sub Permissions
I'm integrating the Google My Business API with Google Cloud Pub/Sub to subscribe to notifications for new reviews. Despite setting up the necessary permissions, I keep encountering the following error when trying to update the notification settings:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS_MISSING_FOR_PUBSUB_TOPIC",
        "domain": "mybusinessnotifications.googleapis.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Pub/Sub Topic Setup:


I created a Pub/Sub topic named gmb-reviews.
Assigned the Pub/Sub Publisher role to the service account (gmb-notifier@karlbook-429614.iam.gserviceaccount.com).
Verified that the permissions are correctly set in the Google Cloud Console.


OAuth2 Token:


The OAuth2 token is generated via a user consent flow and includes the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage scope.
I’ve verified the token using a JWT decoder to ensure it’s associated with the correct account.


API Request:


I’m using the PATCH method to update the notification settings with the following request:

async function subscribeToGMBNotifications(accountId, accessToken) {
  const url = `https://mybusinessnotifications.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/${accountId}/notificationSetting?updateMask=pubsubTopic,notificationTypes`;

  const payload = {
    name: `accounts/${accountId}/notificationSetting`,
    pubsubTopic: `projects/my-project/topics/gmb-reviews`,
    notificationTypes: ['NEW_REVIEW'],
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Subscription successful:', data);
      return data;
    } else {
      const errorData = await response.json();
      console.error('Subscription error:', errorData);
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Network error:', error);
    return null;
  }
}


Verified Pub/Sub IAM Policy:


The IAM policy for the gmb-reviews topic shows that the service account has both Pub/Sub Publisher and Pub/Sub Admin roles.
Question:

Despite setting everything up as described, I keep getting the PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS_MISSING_FOR_PUBSUB_TOPIC error. Could there be something I’m missing in the setup, or is there an additional permission or configuration required for the Google My Business API to publish to Pub/Sub?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @Nouh Belahcen, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

The error message "PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS_MISSING_FOR_PUBSUB_TOPIC,"  that means that the service account you used to set up the subscription does not have the necessary rights to publish messages to the Pub/Sub topic.
You must grant the service account the required IAM roles and permissions in order to fix this problem. You must specifically provide the service account access to the "Pub/Sub Publisher" role on the newly established Pub/Sub topic.
Further steps to give the service account the "Pub/Sub Publisher" role and more details can be found in this documentation. Hope, this might help you.

I'm the owner of the project.

@nouh belahcen
please provide "Healthcare Service Agent" role to the topic  for "mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com"
your issue will be resolved

what do you mean, should I enable the Healthcare service? but why?

"Healthcare Service Agent" role description " Gives the healthcare service account access to networks, Kubernetes Engine and Pub/Sub resources. "
After providing this role, PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS_MISSING_FOR_PUBSUB_TOPIC error resolved for us.

I tried it and I got same error

Here you need to add Pub/Sub Publisher permission to topic NEW_REVIEW.
Here's how to fix it:
1. Go to the Google Cloud Console: Open the Google Cloud Console and navigate to your project that contains the Pub/Sub topic.
2. Find your Pub/Sub topic: Go to the Pub/Sub section and locate the topic projects/my-project/topics/gmb-reviews.
3. Edit permissions:

Click on the topic to view its details.
Find the "Permissions" tab.
Click "Add Principle" to add a new member.


4. Add the service account:

In the "New Principle" field, enter
mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com.

Select the role "Pub/Sub Publisher" from the dropdown.

Click "Save".



Now follow https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/notifications/rest/v1/accounts/updateNotificationSetting
